# How do I remove the decimal .0 arbitrarily inserted after numbers now in a dataframe or series?

Tags: python, dataframe, decimal, series

I imported an Excel file with a column called Zip for Zip Codes. I then tried to use this . .value_counts() to count the zip codes, but the result was a series that added .0 to the ending of every zip code. So, 19999 appeared as 19999.0.

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jms0w.png)

I tried reformatting the Excel file column as Text, but that didn't change anything.

I also converted the series to a dataframe and tried to convert the string to integers using .astype, but that failed as well.

Comment: You probably have a null cell or cells in the column, which converts the type to float. Convert it to `Int64` - i.e., `df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].astype('Int64')`

Comment: @It_is_Chris Zip codes should be strings, not numbers.

Comment: you should read in that column as a string.